# How to collapse multiple variables by column in csv file with R

Tags: r, csv, group-by, aggregate

I've written code to collapse my table, and it works, however whenever I write to a new csv the table seems to not be in the collapsed state. Perhaps this has to do with the summarize function I am using? I am collapsing variables `d1`, `d2`, `d3` for `region_ID`. Is there a way for me put all 3 variables together and save to a new csv?

```
#Collapse the bsu_re_dec.csv table

HI_csv<- read.csv("C:\\filepath\\bsu_re_dec.csv")

HI_csv %>%
group_by(region_ID) %>%
summarize(sum(d1))

HI_csv %>%
group_by(region_ID) %>%
summarize(sum(d2))

HI_csv %>%
group_by(region_ID) %>%    
summarize(sum(d3))
```

Comment: You don't need to separate each: just do `group_by(region_ID) %>% summarise(sum(d1), sum(d2), sum(d3))

Comment: You can export using `write.csv(HI_csv, "/Users/Desktop/HI_data.csv")`

Comment: Thank you. Your comments helped with the collapsing of the table, but when exported it reverts to the non-collapsed version.   Any idea how to maintain the collapsed table?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `summarise_at` to summarise multiple variables

```
library(dplyr)
HI_csv %>%
     group_by(region_ID) %>%
     summarise_at(vars(matches('^d\\d+$')), sum)
```

---

In the devel version of `dplyr`, another option is `across` with `summarise

```
HI_csv %>%
     group_by(region_ID) %>%
     summarise(across(matches('^d\\d+'), sum))
```

Or with a reproducible example

```
iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), sum))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#  <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#1 setosa             250.        171.         73.1        12.3
#2 versicolor         297.        138.        213          66.3
#3 virginica          329.        149.        278.        101.
```

Comment: Will this work in the same way as  `group_by(region_ID) %>% summarise(sum(d1), sum(d2), sum(d3))?  I'm having issues with the export maintaining the collapsed version.

Comment: @bkGeog yes, it would be 3 summarised columns.  But, if you have many number of columns, `summarise_at` would do that without having to manually type `sum` multiple types